VS Code preview for PHP application running in Docker
I am looking for a way to live-preview my website in VS Code, especially for when editing Twig templates.
I have a Symfony project running inside a Docker container (I have 3 separate containers composed together - one with Apache, one with PHP and one with MySQL). All VS Code extensions for live preview I found seem to run their own server, which I don't need, as I run my own server in the Docker.
Is it possible to preview the page in VS Code? Basically all I need is to have a browser window inside VS Code that would refresh either periodically, or when I save a file; to see how the changes I made in my Twig look.
Thanks!

If you run the server already, wouldn't a simple browser extension that does auto-refresh work ?
